# How to use props and navigation together in one functional component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-functional-component

I want to use `props` and `{navigation}` in one functional component in `react-navigation` version 5

This is my code:

```
const Header =(props, {navigation})=>{

return()}
```

But it doesn't work, I can't activate drawer. It returns following error :

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.openDrawer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to lookup destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Example:

```js
const Header = (props)=> {
  const { navigation } = props;

  // Now you can use `navigation`
  // Instead of destructuring, you can also use `props.navigation`
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But i still get above error, I created a header with props and imported that into login screen (i use this header in all screens with different props ) i am trying to make clickable icon on this header and open drawer but it onpress function doesn't work in header component but it works in parent component ( i mean login screen) Do you know how can i fix this?

Comment: Is your header (or stack navigator) inside the drawer navigator?

Comment: Yes please take a look to these screenshots, First one is the drawer configuration and second one is index.js file https://imgur.com/a/hZ86LXk 
https://i.imgur.com/aUTKDRm.jpg

Comment: Your header is a screen in drawer? That doesn't seem right

Comment: I removed it from drawer right now as you said but issue is persisting, It's so weird because  ```navigation.openDrawer();``` works inside parent component (Login screen) but it doesn't work inside child component (Header ) .Do you have any idea?

Comment: Where exactly are you rendering your header?

Comment: It's rendering with parent component, Please take a look at this screenshot. I want when a user click on that icon drawer gets opened, Header is rendered without problem the issue is that onpress function on the icon (touchableopacity) doesn't work inside child component (Header)  https://imgur.com/a/BbIiNer

Comment: I need to see your code. Is your stack navigator/header is inside a screen in drawer? That's where it needs to be. It cannot be a parent of drawer.

Comment: I tried both ( i put it inside a screen drawer and then removed it) in both of status the function didn't work

Comment: Putting it inside a screen in drawer is how it needs to be. If it's not working, then you made a mistake. Read the nesting docs to get familiar with how nesting works https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html

Comment: Ok thank you so much buddy, and thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

If your component is not registered as a route in routes object, you either have to pass the navigation prop manually, or you can do this. Because only the components that are registered as routes will have access to the navigation object.

Wrap it with **withNavigation** from **react-navigation**, like this:

```
import { withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'; 

const YourFunctionalComponent = props => { 
   // your component logic
};

// the navigation now will be in props
export default withNavigation(YourFunctionalComponent)
```

This works with any custom component deep in the tree.